# Disable woocommerce to add cookies to the header so that the dynamic caching could take place

Tags: cookies, woocommerce, header

I am trying to figure out how to disable the woocommerce function which adds cookies to the header of product pages.

I do not have any widget that displays recently viewed products, however when I read the product page header is see: “Set-Cookie : woocommerce_recently_viewed=1491; path=/”.

Extract from the header:
...
server: nginx
set-cookie: woocommerce_recently_viewed=6185%7C281%7C49651%7C1491; path=/
set-cookie: cr_wpml_is_filtered=yes; path=/; SameSite=Lax
vary: Accept-Encoding
...

This cookie in the header does not allow the caching engine to cache the page resulting in very long load time.

I made an extensive search and found out that somebody managed to write a code disabling this function, however I could not see or replicate the code (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/recently-viewed-cookie-causing-cache-bypass-how-to-disable/).

Is there any good person that could help me?

Anita

I analyzed which plugin is adding the cookies to the header. I realized that woocommerce has a function that is doing this. It should be active if there is a recent viewed products widget. However, the function adds the cookies to the header even if there is no widget.